# Product of two sums of inverses of primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

I want to prove that for all $p_1,..., p_k$, $q_1,...q_l$ distincts prime numbers, this equality is false :
$$\left( \sum_{i = 1 }^k \frac{1}{p_i}  \right) \left( \sum_{j=1 }^l \frac{1}{q_j} \right) =1$$

I can prove that $k$ and $l$ must be strictly greater than 1, but nothing else. I tried elementary manipulations and the case k=2 but was not able to make any progress.

Edit :
For the case k = 2 (and the general case), I tried to write the RHS of
$$\frac{1}{p_1} = \frac{1}{\sum_{j} q_j } -\frac{1}{p_2}$$ as an irreducible fraction but was not able to get anything from there.
I also tried to find bounds on the RHS. In the case $k=2$, I can prove that $l\geq 3$ (all primes are $\geq 2$ and if $l=2$ we have a sum of 4 terms of the form $\frac{1}{pq}$ on the LHS. Reasoning this way, we can also get $l\geq 4$ and maybe $5$, but it's not really helping) .

Comment: What did you try for $k=2$? Where does the problem come from?

Comment: I tried elementary manipulations, mostly to write the RHS of $\frac{1}{p_1} = \frac{1}{\sum_{j = 1}^l q_j } -\frac{1}{p_2} $ as an irreducible fraction. The problem comes from numerical simulation of arithmetic derivatives. I did not find any non trivial 2-cycle and tried to prove there was none.

Comment: Can you include your work in the question?

Comment: I added some. I originally did not because nothing seem to work.

Comment: FWIW, no sum of reciprocals of distinct primes can equal an integer. Maybe this can be generalized.

Let $p_0,\dots p_k$ be distinct primes. Let $P=\prod_{i=0}^k p_i$, and call numbers that are divisible by $p_0$ *“peven”* and those that are not divisible by $p_0$ *“podd.”*

Then write the sum with the *peven* common denominator $P$. $$\sum_{i = 0}^k \frac{1}{p_i}=\sum_{i=0}^k{\prod_{j\neq i} p_j\over P}={\textit{podd}\over P}+\sum_{i=\color{red}1}^k{{\textit peven}\over P}={\textit{podd}+\textit{peven}\over\textit{peven}}.$$